# Name arrangement macro

Tags: macros, conditionals

I'm trying to write a c.v. macro. I've got a first, middle and last name and I would like to arrange these as either "first middle last" or as "first last" if middle is unknown

The code I have so far is as follows (which works) :

```
\def\@normalname{
 \@ifundefined{@middlename}
 {
  \@firstname\ \@lastname
 }{
 \@firstname\ \@middlename\ \@lastname
}}
```

and a shorter version that doesn't

```
\def\@normalname{
 \@firstname\
 \@ifundefined{@middlename}{}{\@middlename\ }
 \@lastname
}
```

Any reason why the code would fail in the second case ?

(using pdfLatex if it helps)

Comment: Both versions are working for me (with some superfluous blank spaces that must be elliminated) in some simple test document I created. Can you please elaborate a little more in your question? Perhaps add a minimal version of a document illustrating the problems you are experiencing.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I just saw that the error is in another macro that calls this one. Though I wouldn't have known about the gobble command if I hadn't asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Gonzalo said, if your problem is extra spaces then

```
\def\@normalname{%
 \@firstname\ %(not strictly necessary)
 \@ifundefined{@middlename}{}{\@middlename\ }%
 \@lastname
}
```

is what you need (there are extra spaces in your other version as well). A shorter version is

```
\let\@middlename\@gobble
\def\@normalname{\@firstname\ \@middlename\  \@lastname}
```

as then if you don't define a middle name the default definition eats the extra space, but if you do define it to be a name the following `\` will make a space.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about gobble, also just saw macros2e so I'll look into that.